# Windows XP updates still available after support ends?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, updates

I don't feel like the question belongs in here, but I couldn't find a "Windows" Stackexchange.

The support for Windows XP will end soon - does that mean that any new installations of WinXP don't receive updates anymore? Or are the old updates still available but there won't be new updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that will happen is that Microsoft won't roll out security updates for Windows XP anymore. Also a lot of programs will stop updating, such as antivirus software.

From: http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/software/1304965/when-windows-xp-support-ends-heres-how-to-keep-your-pc-secure

> When Windows XP Support ends in April, it means that Microsoft will no
>   longer be issuing any security updates for this operating system.
>   You'll still be able to download and update patches up to this date,
>   but if a new flaw in the operating system is discovered, it will go
>   unpatched. Potentially, this means that hackers could target the new
>   flaw, letting them infect a Windows XP machine.

It's just a bad idea to keep using XP after April 2014.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I don't know who thought downvoting would be a good idea without supplying any comment.

Comment: (Not downvoter) The basic reason we don't like answering bad questions is because it might attract bad answers, which looks like the reason for the downvote. This, however, is not a bad answer.

Comment: Yeah I really understand. This is a bad question (no offence) but I knew the answer, and could find a source easily. Also I like helping people.